# unable to find explicit activity class for as an asynctask

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting following exception

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.as.as/com.as.as.LoginActivity$myTask}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

No clue as to whats wrong in this

```
<application
        android:name=".ObjectClass.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".PersonalDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_personal_details"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpRegistration.SignUp" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.intsig.ccrengine.ISCardScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Post you activity/asynctask code

Comment: How you do you launch an Activity that is also an ASyncTask? Java can only extend one class so you are either extending from `Activity` or `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

> First try to clean and build project again and then try.
>
> If it's not working then append a full path to your LoginActivity.

For e.g. your package name is **com.exmaple** then you write in your manifest **com.example.LoginActivity** instead of just **.LoginActivity**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating the Intent in the wrong way.

From this line

```
Unable to find explicit activity class  {com.as.as/com.as.as.LoginActivity$myTask};
```

You can tell that you are creating an intent which explicit target is the myTask class, when in reality you want to have the Activity class to be the target class.

Comment: Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myTask.class);
            startActivity(intent1);,this is what i did to call my Async Task

Comment: It should be `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);` the second parameter is the activity you want to start.

Comment: I'm new to this,i have a class which does something,its not an activity,but at the end of that class i want to jump to an AsyncTask,finish that and come back,how can i do this ??

Comment: Please read the documentation on AsyncTask and Activity. You are not close to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your creating activity code is wrong.

```
new Intent(getBaseContext(), myTask.class);
```

This code trying to open activity from `myTask` class. Guess you are waiting for following code:

```
new Intent(getBaseContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
```

Comment: I'm new to this,i have a class which does something,its not an activity,but at the end of that class i want to jump to an AsyncTask,finish that and come back,how can i do this ??